# Safari vh + max-height + justify-content: center bug?

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

Consider this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: teal;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20vh;
  max-height: 20px;
}
```

Chrome (57), Firefox (52), IE (Edge) render is like so:

[image: Chrome]

But Safari (Version 9 on a Mac with OS X) renders it like so:

[image: Safari]

I consider Safari's rendering wrong, tell me if you disagree.

If you remove either `justify-content: center` or `max-height: 20px` or change `height: 20vh` to `height: 20px` Safari renders like the other browsers (what I would consider correct).

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmrOjq

Is this a known Safari bug? Am I miss using flex-box here?

Comment: Could be a bug. It's an unusual layout structure. `flex-direction: column`, but there are no stacking items, and `justify-content: center` on a container where it can't possibly work. What's the goal?

Comment: @Michael_B yeah, that's what I felt too after thinking about it.. doesn't seem to be any goal here :) The `justify-content: center` was just left from before when I had a height on the parent. But thanks for your comment! I guess we categorize this more as "miss use" than "painful bug".